# Visual Studio Multi-device project keeps on hanging intermittently in Ripple

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, ripple, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm currently using Visual Studio Premium 2013 under Windows 7 x86 and after installing Visual Studio Updates 4 and the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.0 my existing multi-device hybrid project keeps on hanging intermittently for about 3 to 6 minutes after running that project in Ripple. Afterwards I got the messages:

> Unable to get Ripple session info for port 9223.
>
> A required web socket component is missing. Please refer to the
>   documentation at    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=403596.*

I already have the *websocket4net.dll* installed at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows\" but just to be sure I have downloaded the latest version from this site https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/ but it didn't help at all.

Can anyone please advise what to do as this is really extremely frustrating. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To investigate this issue further - did you upgrade from CTP2.0 to CTP3.0?  If so, did you encounter any issues during the upgrade?  Did this issue ever occur with CTP2.0? You mention it is intermittent - how frequently does it occur?

Comment: Thanks Ellen, this started to happens after upgrading CTP2.0 to CTP3.0. I haven't had an issue like this from CTP2.0. The problem occured randomly whenever I run my project, it could occur on the first, second, third re-runs. It more likely to occur on the second or succedding runs though. I ended up not using visual studio for doing my project, I simply hosted it on IIS and continued testing it in Chrome+Ripple, my editor is NOTEPAD++, this works well for me at the moment.

Comment: I have the same issue. Has anyone solved this? Repair with vs2013mda_0.3.exe also did not work.

Comment: Hi Jasper2, I've decided not to use Visual Studio when testing my project in Rippler, it just caused me a lot of headaches. I'll try again when it get into RTM, well hopefully it won't have this problem.

Comment: @allan Have you tried to disable your firewall?  It was in the list of things to check when I was struggling with VS2015 Preview.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with the RTM release of Visual Studio 2015 and the Tools for Apache Cordova. If you still have this issue, I suggest submitting a bug report  on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.